# Getting an Access Token with Xml HTTP Request

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, access-token

I am having some trouble getting an access token from a site for a web application. The response to the following is

`"{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"The grant type was not specified in the request"}"`.

I have specified the grant type below but it seems I have not formatted the request correctly.

Any suggestions?

```
  var getToken = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
  getToken.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  getToken.open("POST", "https://api2.libcal.com/1.1/oauth/token", true); 
  getToken.send('grant_type=client_credentials','client_id=XXX', 'client_secret=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
```

Comment: You probably want to set these params as query params.

Comment: Are you the developer of the web-service which  provides the access token? If not, you should ask the service provider which are the correct grant types

Comment: The documentation for this site says the grant type should be client credentials. I can get an access token using a third party program like Postman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are doing a Post Request to get an access token , the parameters should be send in the body (JSON) like below :  (I tested ,it works fine )

```
  // form data for the post request
  var data = {
    "grant_type":"client_credentials",
    "client_id": "XXX",
    "client_secret": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  };


  // construct an HTTP request
  var getToken= new XMLHttpRequest();
  getToken.open("POST", "https://api2.libcal.com/1.1/oauth/token", true);
  getToken.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  // send the collected data as JSON
  getToken.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: This response might be true and return token correctly. But it doesn't explain how to access the token after the request is approved by the server. If You could please point out how to correctly reference the object `getToken` to have the token value saved in a variable?